# I can't post with retrofit in real device but it works in emulator

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have an app that posting file with some string. I used retrofit 2. Everything is OK. but I have a problem. I run app in emulator an it works fine and goes to onResponse and post file and strings, but when I run app in real device it doesn't work and goes to onFailure in retrofit. What is the problem. I use galaxy s6 edge with android 7 API 24. and emulator is android 7.1.1 API 25. please help I should fix this problem :(

**this is my retrofit code:**

```
            if (name.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    description.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    deadline.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                popupForErrorEmptyField();
            } else {
                Client client = ServiceGenerator.createService(Client.class);
                File file = null;
                RequestBody requestFile = null;
                MultipartBody.Part body = null;
                if (userProfileImagePath != null) {
                    try {
                        file = new File(userProfileImagePath);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            Log.i("finaltest", "found");
                            requestFile =
                                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getMimeType(uri)), file);
                            body =
                                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("projectFile", file.getName(), requestFile);
                        } else {
                            Log.i("finaltest", "not found");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }

                RequestBody nameRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name.getText().toString().trim());
                RequestBody amountRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), amount.getText().toString().trim());
                RequestBody descriptionRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), description.getText().toString().trim());
                RequestBody categoryRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), category.getSelectedItem().toString());
                RequestBody deadlineRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), deadline.getText().toString().trim());
                Call<AddProjectResponse> call = client.addProject(
                        token,
                        body,
                        nameRequestBody,
                        amountRequestBody,
                        descriptionRequestBody,
                        categoryRequestBody,
                        deadlineRequestBody);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<AddProjectResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AddProjectResponse> call,
                                           Response<AddProjectResponse> response) {
                        Log.e("xcxc", "code:" + response.code());
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("xcxc", "success:");
                            popupForSuccessAddingProject();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "successfull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AddProjectResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("test123", "error in add project");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: When it fails what exception does it throw?

Comment: in logcat show this  Log.e("test123", "error in add project");

Comment: I pickjfile correctly

Comment: that is your log which does not tell us anything. Replace 
`Log.e("test123", "error in add project");` with
`Log.e("test123", "error:"+t.getErrorMessage());`

Comment: it shows this :     E/test123: Handshake failed

Comment: Ok, this is not the solution but try to change your base url from https to http and see if you will be able to execute a request then

Comment: I change base URL but it doesn't work

Comment: what is the version of your retrofit and okHttp library?

Comment: I have another problem I have this error   E/test123: timeout

Comment: I used this version 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will solve everyone's problems, in my case it's one filed was expired which got the server run into crash, since it's working on the emulator and not on physical device do the following:

1. get Postman to use it in testing.
2. use the retrofit logger interceptor to collect the logs and get the all values of the request from both physical device and emulator
3. try the working request body on postman(in this case the emulator)
4. try to replace each field of the working request body(emulator) in postman with it's corresponding one from the not working request body (real device) and test the request at each change until one of them causes an error.

in my case the userId was expired and this cause an error from the server